# Rails Caches_Page being misplaced due to namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a controller within a namespace and would like to cache it's Index.  I am successfully caching pages that are not under a namespace, and successfully caching fragments as well.

When I visit http//.../house/kitchen it successfully creates /public/house/kitchen.html. However it never finds it, so it is always writing over the cached file.

I haven't been able to find an option with cache_page or caches_page to help me direct the cached file in the correct location.

Another frustrating thing is that http//.../house/kitchen/table successfully reads and creates /public/houose/kitchen/table/new.html.

I would greatly appreciate any direction!

**Edit:** adding details
Ruby : 1.8.7
Rails: 2.3.5
Server: Mongrel

**Edit:** I've placed kitchen.html in every possible location in my public folder, this controller seems just to refuse reading it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not use namespaces, anything you want to do in regards to urls can be done with routing.  Is there a reason why you have to use namespaced controllers?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the app.  Once I bang my head against the wall long enough, and can demonstrate that removing the namespacing will resolve the problem, then it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is relevant but I found there was an [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-924) with goldspike web server a while ago.
So maybe your web server also is missing something (BTW, what a web server are you using)?

Comment: currently using mongrel.  I don't believe this is related as mongrel is successfully doing this with fragments, and page views that are not namespaced.

Comment: I do not see obvious reasons looking at http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb

but you could give it a try, maybe you'll spot something.
Maybe that there is something to do with the web server itself...

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm having the same issue. If so, I know the cause, but haven't yet found a solution.

The web server finds the directory `http://…/house/kitchen/` before it finds the file `http://…/house/kitchen.html`. This directory doesn't contain an `index.html`, so it passes the route to Rails which kindly generates a new file.

So, you could:

1. Place your cached file at `http://…/house/kitchen/index.html`
2. Tell your web server to look for `*.html` files before it looks for `*/` directories.